# Can't ask permission at runtime (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am following a video on Lynda.com and i am trying to
request permissions at runtime. But i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
at com.doppler.stackingcoder.pechhulp.PechhulpActivity.makeCall(PechhulpActivity.java:226)
```

Here is the method where the error appears:

```
public void makeCall() {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:09003344556"));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            PechhulpActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) // Line 226 (Error)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(PechhulpActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
            Toast.makeText(PechhulpActivity.this, "I know you said no, but I'm asking again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PechhulpActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        return;
    }
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

I hope someone knows why this error appears. Here is a gist of my full class:
https://gist.github.com/soufyanekaddouri/812f65669847619e3af7016403b1e7be

Answer (score 0):

You are passing PechhulpActivity.this as the Context but it seems that this is actually a null reference.
I suggest trying to resolve the Context in some other way (i.e. getApplicationContext(), saving the Context as global variable etc...).

Here is an example of how to access your application context:

```
public class PechhulpActivity extends Activity{

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        ...
        ...
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you give me a example?